# Jest and Enzyme simulating an input field's onClick method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing tests for a simple password update component.  My component has an input field with `type="checkbox"` with an `onClick` function.  When the input checkbox is clicked I expect my `togglePassword` function to run.  The actual function is working properly however, in my tests I am not able to simulate the onClick event.

My input field looks like this:

```
<input
  id="toggle-password"
  type="checkbox"
  onClick={() => togglePassword()}
/>
```

and the `togglePassword` function:

```
  const togglePassword = () => {
    if (passType === "password") {
      setPassType("text");
    } else {
      setPassType("password");
    }
  };
```

the hook that gets updated:

```
const [passType, setPassType] = useState("password");
```

lastly the input field which used `passType`:

```
<input id="create-password" type={passType} required />
```

All of this is pretty straight forward and should be fairly easy to test. I begin my test by making sure that the `create-password` input field has `type=password`.  Then I try to simulate a click (thus calling `togglePassword`) and I expect my input field type to have `type="text"`.

I have tried using `simulate("click")`, `prop("onClick")()`, `simulate("change", {target: {value: "checked"}})`, and a couple other techniques I have found on S.O.  Nothing has worked.

Here is my current test:

```
it("toggles passwords", () => {
  const onMock = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(
    <NoAuthPasswordChange handleSubmit={onMock}  />
  );
  const form = wrapper.find("#no-auth-password-change-form");
  const createPass = form.find("#create-password");
  const togglePass = form.find("#toggle-password");
  createPass.simulate("change", { target: { value: "12345" } });
  expect(createPass.props().type).toEqual("password");
  togglePass.simulate("click");
  wrapper.update();
  expect(createPass.props().type).toEqual("text");
});
```

I put in a test to see if the `togglePassword` function is being called and it is not.  I've looking at this for a while and I am really not sure how to call the `onClick` method here.